# Vim printing strange characters when hit "home", "end" stc

Tags: key-bindings, terminal, keyboard-layout

Why vim keep printing strange characters when I hit non-characters key?

- <kbd>Insert</kbd> prints `[2~`
- <kbd>Delete</kbd> prints `[3~`
- <kbd>Page Up</kbd> prints `[5~`
- <kbd>Page Down</kbd> prints `[6~`
- <kbd>Home</kbd> prints `OH`
- <kbd>End</kbd> prints `OF`
- <kbd>Arrow Up</kbd> prints `OA`
- <kbd>Arrow Down</kbd> prints `OB`
- <kbd>Arrow Right</kbd> prints `OC`
- <kbd>Arrow Left</kbd> prints `OD`

How can I fix this?

Comment: what terminal are you using?

Comment: Terminator and run on Arch linux

Comment: These chars are the representation of the key you pressed.

Comment: These are the escape sequences sent by the keys minus the initial escape character. Are they printed in the status line? Normally they should be recorded in the terminal database and vim should find them on its own. What is the value of the `TERM` environment variable? Do other terminal applications (`less`, `bash`, …) recognize the keys properly? Do the keys work in other terminal emulators? Do you have the same problem if you run `vim -u /dev/null`?

Comment: It's only happens on vim.  Works in terminal emulator. I've tried to use `xterm` and `linux` on `TERM` environment variable. Both have no effects. I`ve tried every possible value for set term inside vim too. It still has no any effects

Comment: @BagolDaplun do you have a vimrc? (Are you in nocompatible mode?)

Comment: Yes, I have `.vimrc`. And I put `set nocompatible` there.

Comment: @BagolDaplun, Did you already try starting vim with `vim -Nu NONE` and seeing if the problem is reproducible?

Comment: I tried just now. It's not printing strange charactes, but my settings in  `.vimrc` are not loaded. So, could be the problem reside in `.vimrc` file? And what could it be?

Answer (score 3):

According to Terminator's [FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/jessies/wiki/TerminatorFAQ):

1. You should set `TERM = terminator` because it uses a non-conventional terminfo file.
2. You should guarantee that you don't have vim-minimal (or similar) package, because it might not include support for terminfo.